# C# WinForms | Picturebox white bleeding right & bottom edges

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, stretching

Hello Stackoverflow Community.

I currently work on an application which has a cursor region magnifyer feature, for the user to pick a color.

However, i've the problem that the Picturebox has white edges on the right and bottom, even though the image captured is only one dark color.

The captured screen is 10x10 pixel and the Picturebox is 80x80 pixel and it's SizeMode set to StretchImage.

I checked if the raw captured image maybe contains this edges already by saving it and checking it in Photoshop. But the raw captured image is fine, so it must be something weird with the Picturebox.

Here you can see how it looks (The mousecursor and the capture-region[green rectangle] are just painted on the screenshot for demonstration, as i was not able to screen my cursor, and yes - the green region is painted way too large, it should be just 10x10 pixel ^^)

[image]

Has it maybe something to do with the way the Image get's stretched internally? If so, is there any, not too complicated way around it?

I appreciate any help in advance :)

//Edit: I think it's actually about the stretching
I found this topic [Image after resize has white border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626985/image-after-resize-has-white-border) but i don't know what the GetSize() Method is, or where it is (from)

Have a great day!

Comment: Check the `BorderStyle` property on the picture box. If it's 3D, it might be causing this

Comment: Hello, i already checked that but i think it's about the stretching. It's stretching 10x10 pixel into 80x80

I found this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626985/image-after-resize-has-white-border but i don't know what the GetSize() Method is, or where it is (from)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the edges [here](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/preventing-ghost-borders-when-resizing-images-with-system-drawing), as you can see in the first screen. However, in the second screen you can see a 2x2 pixel capture, stretched to 80x80 pixel with the found "solution", will mix colors as it's actually 80x80 pixel in the end, while i want to have it displaying the raw pixels, so, 3 black ones and one white one in this case. Now i am even more stuck ^^
I guess i should instead read the pixel colors of the single pixels from captured image and set the colors in the preview picturebox, or make 4 panels in the case of just 2x2 pixels

```
public new Image Resize(Image image, int targetWidth, int targetHeight)
{
    var resizedImage = new Bitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage))
    {
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        var attributes = new ImageAttributes();
        attributes.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
        var destination = new Rectangle(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight);
        graphics.DrawImage(image, destination, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);
    }

    return resizedImage;
}
```

[image]

[image]

//Edit:
Okay i think i'm gonna use Get/SetPixel or Panels(for small captures), as i did here on the right, the left is still the 80x80 Picturebox
[image]

Comment: Use InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor

Comment: Many many thanks